Spring Boot で Controller と Service クラスのすみわけ
Spring BootでRestAPIを実装しようとしています。
ControllerではHTTPステータスを返すための判断処理、
Serviceではロジック的な処理を記載すると思います。

データベースに必要なデータAが無い場合、HTTPステータス404とメッセージA
1で必要なデータAに紐づくデータBがさらに無い場合HTTPステータス404とメッセージB
2のデータがあれば必要なデータを返す

このような場合、ControllerとServiceはどのように分けるべきなのでしょうか？
Aのパターン
Controllerクラスで

データAを抽出するようなServiceクラスのメソッドを呼ぶ
→Serviceクラスのメソッドの戻り値にデータがなければHTTPステータス404とメッセージAを返して終了
データBを抽出するようなServiceクラスのメソッドを呼ぶ
→Serviceクラスのメソッドの戻り値にデータがなければHTTPステータス404とメッセージBを返して終了
HTTPステータス200と取得したデータを返して終了

Bのパターン
Controllerクラスで

すでべを実施してくれるServiceクラスのメソッドを呼ぶ
→Serviceクラスのメソッドでは、HTTPステータスとメッセージ、あるいはHTTPステータスと取得データを戻り値に返す
Serviceクラスの戻り値を返して終了

どちらのパターンでも期待通り動くかと思います。
ただ、Aのパターンですと１、２のパターンでトランザクションが別になってしまうと思います。
BのパターンではServiceクラスのメソッドの責務が多くなってしまいます（ServiceクラスでHTTPステータスとかを持たせたくない気持ちもあります）
有識者の皆さんはどのようにControllerとServiceを切り分けていらっしゃいますか？

Controller で 'データA' を使わないのであれば、Service 側は 'データB' を返すメソッドを１つだけ定義して、データ A or B が無かったら RuntimeException を継承したカスタム例外クラスにメッセージ A or B を詰めて throw する。Controller 側は Service から 'データB' を受け取って 200 を返すのが正常系で、try/catch でカスタム例外を捕まえたら getMessage() でメッセージを取り出して 404 を返す、で挙がっている要件は満たせそうですね。
Controller で 'データA' と 'データB' が両方必要とか、より複雑な要件の場合は service メソッドから複数のデータ（場合によってはエラー情報なども）を格納するクラス（所謂 DTO）を返すようにします。

コメントありがとうございます。例外を継承させて、、、というあたりを全く考えていなかったので、大変勉強になりました。今回はこちらで試したいと思います。
（必要データなどが出てきたときにさらにSharedServiceを考えていきます）

もう1レイヤー定義するというのをよく経験しました。TERASOLUNAのドキュメント

3.2.5.2. Serviceのクラス構成

で説明されている

Controller
Service
SharedService

のような構成です。
自分はこういう命名をしたことは無いですが、検索してみるとそれなりに流通している用語のように見えます。
(TERASOLUNAのドキュメントでは共通化処理のためにレイヤーを増やしていますが(それが名前にも表れている)、私がレイヤーを増やすのはまさに質問文中の懸念事項に対処するためです)

質問文中の話を例にすると、Controllerは

すでべを実施してくれるServiceクラスのメソッドを呼ぶ

が、その後Serviceは

データAを抽出するような

SharedServiceのメソッドと、

データBを抽出するような

SharedServiceのメソッドをそれぞれ呼び、得られた必要なデータをControllerに返す、といったところでしょうか。

回答ありがとうございます。まずはSharedServiceを調べてみたいと思います

SharedServiceについても試してみました。Serviceでトランザクションをはり、そのなかでSharedServiceを呼び出しているということですね。勉強になりました。
